# string concatenation in macro C

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-strings

In C, I have two macros

```
Edit:

#define macro1(name , number , date ){\
 <---------body------>
 }


#define macro2(key){\
 <------body----->
 }
```

I have to combine the name( a `char *` variable) , number (an integer) , date(another `char*` variable) and send it as a string to the `macro2` which will be called from the `macro1`.

I'm trying to do it by declaring a char* variable in macro 1 and use snprintf. Is this a good idea ?

P.S : I'm converting the into a string and then combining them.

Comment: what is "def" ?

Comment: This is not C. Or C++. Please use real code, and proper tagging, since tags is how people who can help find your question.

Comment: What is "Edit:" ??

Comment: Are `name`/`date` literal strings, or regular variables ?

Comment: You write _I'm trying to do it by declaring a char* variable in macro 1 and use snprintf._. It could be interesting to show us your attempt instead of _<---------body------>_.

Comment: Why not use functions instead of using macros ?

Comment: Despite the lack of actual code, it seems to me that you're trying to use a macro to do computations on run-time values. That's not going to work. I suggest you use an ordinary function again. Then the code will be readable and, first of all, it will also work. Only use macros when you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Function in c++:

```
std::string concat(const std::string& name, int number, const std::string& date)
{
    return name + std::to_string(number) + date;
}
```

Macro for literals c-strings:

```
#define MACRO(name, number, date) name #number date
```

Comment: how this macro will get working for non "inline" strings?

Comment: @Nick: For non literal c-strings, using function is better, as MACRO does provide any improvement than regular function. (and even for literal I would use function).

Comment: but function using `std::string`, not `char *`. macro will work only if you do MACRO("string", 5, "DATE"). it will not work if you pass variables, even const ones.

Comment: @Nick: If you pass variable, prefer function over MACRO. (I don't show the way to handle variable in macro on purpose).

Comment: sure. but it is std::string and he probably is doing his homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this with macros, it will get too big and messy.

Instead of macros, you can do this with inline function. This is more C++ way, but it will work great in C too:

```
inline const char *macro1(const char *name, int const number, const char *date, char *buffer, size_t const buffer_size){
    // copy everything into the buffer, probably with sprintf()
    return buffer;
}
```

in case of C, I also suggest function to be defined as:

```
static inline const char *macro1(const char *name, int const number, const char *date, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size);
```

but this will not always compiled in C++.

**Update:**

As 5gon12eder mentioned, it does compiles on gcc 6.2.1 and clang 3.8.1.

For C++ instead of `static` you can use anonymous namespace:

```
namespace{
    inline const char *macro1(const char *name, int const number, const char *date, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size);
}
```

Finally, if you plan to use the string just to print it, or put it into a file, do not concatenate, but just do it in this function.

Comment: Why use `static` only in C? Or did you mean that an anonymous `namespace` should be used instead in C++? Also, the “C++ way” doesn't look very C++ to me, compared to, eg, Jarod42's solution.

Comment: @5gon12eder - both "static inline" will not compile on C++. I decided not to mention for anonymous namespace. I believe he is using this for school and of course they learning C by calling it C++.

Comment: I'm not aware that `static inline` is not allowed in C++. Your conjecture about C and C++ in school might be correct, though.

Comment: you are correct. I swear I had to remove it on 20+ lines year ago in order to compile. not remember what version of gcc it was.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define STR1  "wel "

#define STR2  "come"

#define STR3  STR1 ## STR2
```

OR

```
#define STR1  "wel "

#define STR2  "come"

#define STR3 STR1 STR2
```

Comment: `##` operator is for concatenating tokens, for example variable names, and results in new token, NOT string. `#define STR3  STR1 ## STR2` will produce token STR1STR2, and because there is no such macro name, nor variable name, function name, etc. compilation will fail. Second example concatenates two string literals, while OP asked for concatenation of `char *` variables and an integer literal.